# Is it git or text editor making copy of same file?

Tags: git, version-control, text-editor

I am using git and it makes copies of same file while I am working. It looks something like this on command line:

```
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb~
```

Why does it happen? Am I missing something or doing it wrong way?

Comment: Could it be your text editor? See [git creates files ending in ~?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234207/git-creates-files-ending-in)

Comment: Vim saves tmp files like that or similar I think. Using vim??

Comment: It is gedit+gmate I am using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git isnt doing anything actively in the repo. It only does something when you initiated commands. Its your text editor creating a working version of your current script. If you want you can add the file pattern ~* to your .gitignore file

Comment: Yeah, it is editor creating working copy. I checked and added *~ on .gitignore. Thanks a lot.