# .gitignore for file extension( ~) not working

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to ignore all the files that ends with ~.

My .gitignore fille is

*~

I have placed .gitignore file as below.

sci2c|
     |2.3.1
           |various files and folders
           |.gitignore

Its not ignoring the files thats ends with ~ in all directories.

Please help.

Comment: Already addressed in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234207/git-creates-files-ending-in

Comment: @FrancisRegan I don't see where OP's question is addressed on that thread

Comment: what is "sci2c| |2.3.1 |various files and folders |.gitignore" supposed to indicate?

Comment: It should be ignoring them. Are you the problem is not that those files were already under version control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is already added in to repository then you need to remove them. Git thinks of its data more like a set of [snapshots](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics) of a miniature filesystem. Every time you commit, or save the state of your project in Git, it basically takes a picture of what all your files look like at that moment and stores a reference to that snapshot. To be efficient, if files have not changed, Git doesn’t store the file again, just a link to the previous identical file it has already stored. Git thinks about its data more like a stream of snapshots. So you need to remove the already added files then

> git rm --cached file-1 file-2..... file-n

Then the files listed in gitignore will work as expected. Check the notes section in the [Git Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: I have used git rm --cached .

Comment: Then
git add .
git commit -m "msg"
this has worked for me

Answer (score 1):

`*~.*` should work for all such files on any extension.